# Submiting a Form from Angular to Laravel controller

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

Im trying to submit a form from angular to a controller in laravel because i need to use it to generate the url of the api i need to consume.
I was wondering if someone could give me a hint about how to do it.

```
  onsubmit(){
  
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/mov', this.form).subscribe(
          data=>console.log(data),
          error=>console.log(error)
         )
      }
```

My controller:

```
class controllermov extends Controller
{
    public function mov(Request $request)
    {
    
        $id=$request['ClientId'];
        $df=$request['datefrom'];
        $dt=$request['dateTo'];
        $response=Http::get("http://132.148.19.159:80/api/account/Get/$id?datefrom=$df&dateTo=$dt");
        $data=$response->json();
        return $data;

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `$request->input('ClientId');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure with the less information provided but this should work fine, first in angularjs

```
onsubmit(){
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/mov', JSON.stringify(this.form)).subscribe(
          data=>console.log(data),
          error=>console.log(error)
         )
      }
```

For your controller

```
class controllermov extends Controller
{
    public function mov(Request $request)
    {
        // assuming that the key names are ClientId,datefrom,dateTo
        $id=$request->input('ClientId');
        $df=$request->input('datefrom');
        $dt=$request->input('dateTo');

        try{
            $response=Http::get("http://132.148.19.159:80/api/account/Get/$id?datefrom=$df&dateTo=$dt");
            if($response->successful()){
                return $response->json();
            }else{
                $response->throw();
            }   
        }catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```